# Switch from App Service Plan to Azure Functions Premium Plan

Tags: azure-functions

It is now possible to switch from an App Service Plan to an Azure Functions Premium Plan. Or is it?

After switching it works initially but it shows an error: "Storage is not configured properly, Function scaling will be limited."

[image]

The [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) are to add the following two items to the configuration:

1. WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING
2. WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE

**WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING** seems easy, because it should just have the same content as AzureWebJobsStorage as far as I understand:

> DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[name];AccountKey=[key]

**WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE** is less easy, because it says "Default is a unique string that begins with the function app name.". So I improvised that by putting my app service name and I added "091999e2" just like it says in the sample.

Now, after saving this configuration, the Function App tries to start again but it cannot start. It responds with "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."

Clearly the configuration is not working. After removing the configuration again it starts working again (but again with the warning of being unable to scale).

So what is the correct way of adding this configuration after moving a Function App from App Service Plan to Functions Premium Plan?

Answer (score 2):

For me the "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE" contains just the same Azure Function name if that doesn't fix it, I would say some other value is missing so maybe you could compare a newly created function with all values it has to your current App Service Plan. If you are using ARM template, maybe there is another binding setting missing so take a look at the different approaches [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code#deploy-on-premium-plan).

Comment: Good idea. I just created a new Function to check the default configuration and it had added this string to the end of my function name in the WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE setting: 84c8

Comment: I forgot to update you. This did not lead to anything else. There were no other differences and changing the value to the same as the function name did not do the trick.

Comment: This worked for me, I put the Connection String (without ;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net) in WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and the functions name in WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE. Check also the answer of this post: https://www.connected-pawns.com/2020/06/14/azure-function-apps-storage-is-not-configured/